# How to change from string to integer when converting from CSV to JSON?

Tags: javascript, python, json, csv, integer

I found this code in order to convert a CSV file into JSON. But I need in this case a *credit* field to be an `integer`, therefore it shouldn't be enclosed into the quote marks `""`.

I used this code rather than a simple converter since I'm using the nested loops:

```
**Import**
import csv
import json
from itertools import groupby

**Accessing csv** 
with open('testing.csv', 'r') as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r]

    groups = []

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['ref_num'], r['date'])):
        groups.append({
            "date": k[1],
            "ref_num": k[0],
            "items": [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['ref_num', 'date']} for d in list(g)]
        })

print(json.dumps(groups[:10], indent=4))
```

**THIS IS THE OUTPUT**

```
"date": "2018-12-28",
        "ref_num": "PV18/12/066",
        "items": [
            {
                "description": "Jacky",
                "debit": "",
                "credit": "59.80",
                "coa_code": "310-1000",
                "coa_name": "Samboi"
            },
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT - LOOK AT THE CREDIT property**

```
"date": "2018-12-28",
        "ref_num": "PV18/12/066",
        "items": [
            {
                "description": "Jacky",
                "debit": "",
                "credit": 59.80,
                "coa_code": "310-1000",
                "coa_name": "Samboi"
            },
```

Could you please advise me on how I can convert an `integer string` into `integer` while transforming from CSV into JSON structure?

Comment: You have an identified value that you want to convert from string to numeric.  Where are you stuck?  That part is a direct browser search, or any string/numeric tutorial.

Comment: I searched but i was not able to do it. Im new to programming

Comment: "not able to do it" is not a SO (Stack Overflow) problem specification.  You need to locate the string, identify its type, and convert (likely with `float(string)`).  Each of these is covered by documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Doing K[2] to locate the string is not working

Comment: Again, "not working" is not a SO specification.  Update your posting with the specific problem; provide us the expected [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and we can help -- and I'll be happy to rescind my closure and down-votes.

Comment: Before that, though, see this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.  Start with your most direct diagnostic tool: `print`.  Display the values of variables as you go, so you *know* what data you're manipulating at each point.  When you get *stuck*, you'll already have an execution trace to post for us.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need it like that? Valid JSON will always have the quotes around it I think. You can JSON parse it and convert it into a javascript object. Then you can convert the string to number for the specific value you need to use.

When you fetch the credit later to use it. You can convert it to number then like that:

var creditNum = parseFloat(data.items[0].credit);

Comment: Since the app im buiidng that particular value need to be integer

Comment: Under the for loop or before?